# How to abort generation and print an error message to the user

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm developing a Yeoman generator. In my generator I receive user's input via prompts. Some of the values user inputs of course require validation.

My question is that; How can I abort the process if validation did not pass and print a custom error message to the user?

Comment: DId u solve this issue?

Comment: No. But thanks for the tip though :)

Answer (score 2):

I didnt find any solution mo elegant than this, but it works:

```
throw new Error("Some error message!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply return the string message in validate function

```
validate: function(username){
  if(username.trim().length == 0)
    return "Your username is required !";

  return !username.trim().length == 0
}
```